# How to edit the orginal value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x=0

for x in range(0,k):
    if(x>list_length):
        x=0
    #adding value of list in position 'x' to concat list
    concat_list.append(l[x])
    x+=1
```

I want to edit the real value(defined outside the for loop) of x in "if statement". How can I do that?

Comment: don't use `x` as loop variable at the same time...

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to redefine the original value `x`, then redefine your `for` loop variable (i.e. `for x in range(0, k)` to `for i in range(0, k)`).

Comment: what is I point another variable as same address as 'x' and edit its value?

Comment: No, the variable `i` inside of the `for` loop is not the same is `x` and will not override its data (until the user manually does that). Not only that, it will be deleted after the `for` loop is over.